# Play MP3 files in order without HTML5 audio with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mp3, articulate-storyline

I'm trying to play three MP3 files one after another using Javascript without the HTML5 audio tag. 
[I'm working within Articulate Storyline which is an authoring tool for eLearning. It supports Javascript within files but not HTML]

So far, the best I've got is the following which plays all at the same time:

```
function myFunction() {
    var audio1 = new Audio('http://www.mysite.co.uk/h/welcome.mp3');
    var audio2 = new Audio('http://www.mysite.co.uk/h/name.mp3');
    var audio3 = new Audio('http://www.mysite.co.uk/h/cont.mp3');

    audio1.play();
    audio2.play();
    audio3.play();
}
```

I've considered a 'wait' function, but I only know how to do this properly with JQuery, and if I'm recalling correctly, Articulate Storyline does not support JQuery even if it is hosted elsewhere.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event handler that listens for the audio play to end, and then play the next one etc.

```
function play(audio) {
    audio.play();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        audio.addEventListener('ended', resolve);
    });
}

function myFunction() {
    var audio1 = new Audio('http://www.mysite.co.uk/h/welcome.mp3');
    var audio2 = new Audio('http://www.mysite.co.uk/h/name.mp3');
    var audio3 = new Audio('http://www.mysite.co.uk/h/cont.mp3');

    play(audio1).then(function() {
        return play(audio2);
    }).then(function() {
        return play(audio3);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! Works beautifully with the code I've prewritten to get the users name variable too.  
Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the audio **onended** event . Just listen for one player to stop then play the next .

Example :
One way is to add your players to an array for better control

```
var players = [audio1,audio2,audio3];

    var counter = 0;

    audio1.onended = playNext;



    function playNext(){
         if(counter <= players.length){
          counter++
          players[counter].play();
          players[counter].onended = playNext;
    }
   }
```

oneneded  : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method for play unlimited files:

```
PlayAll= function (pathList) {

    if(pathList.length>0){
      var audio = new Audio(pathList[0]);
      if(pathList.length>1){
         var count = 1;
         $(audio).on('ended', function () {
            if (count < pathList.length) {
               audio.src =  pathList[count];
               audio.play();
               count++;
            }
         });
      }
      audio.play()
   }
};
```